# What is a good jQuery lightbox clone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox

It must be:

- easily skinnable with css
- be able to handle forms and not just images
- be well documented

Any suggestions welcome

Many thanks

Comment: thanks in advance for all suggestions ill post which i plump for l8r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Shadowbox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/support.html#adapters) on several large projects and it works great.

> Although Shadowbox can be used in
>   standalone mode, it's just as easy to
>   use Shadowbox with your JavaScript
>   library of choice for a given project.
>   This is accomplished using adapters.
>   An adapter is a small file that tells
>   Shadowbox which methods to call on the
>   underlying framework to achieve some
>   common purpose such as querying the
>   DOM or handling events. Shadowbox
>   comes bundled with adapters for the
>   following JavaScript frameworks:
>
> ```
> * Prototype
> * jQuery
> * MooTools (requires 1.2 Core)
> * Dojo Toolkit
> * Yahoo! User Interface Library (requires yahoo-dom-event.js)
> * Ext (requires ext-core.js)
> ```

Comment: Hi All thanks for the suggetions

I went for Shadowbox, I'd seen it before and considered it on a Mootools project but never taken it any further

Not convinced about the quality of documentation but I have it skinned and doing everything i want

Thanks again everyone

Answer (score 1):

[Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)?

Comment: I don't like Thickbox's default transition mechanism, out-of-the-box much prefer Shadowbox.js.  I'm not even sure to what degree you can customize Thickbox though I'm sure it's probably quite extensive.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say either [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) or [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) (though ThickBox is good too).

Answer (score 1):

I recently went though a whole lot of them and found [Pretty Photo](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) my favourite

Answer (score 0):

[Superbox!](http://www.pierrebertet.net/projects/jquery_superbox/) is also a nice Lightbox clone. Its easily and entirely CSS stylable.

Answer (score 0):

[High Slide](http://highslide.com/) is nice also asp.net control version of HighSlide is available [here](http://encosia.com/downloads/highslide-js-net/)